# Monodevelop invalid pointer crash

Tags: memory, monodevelop, backtrace, invalid-pointer

I downloaded MonoDevelop from the Debian Testing repositories and tried to use it, at first everything went ok, the program starts nicely but when it comes to create a project or a solution or even opening a file it suddenly crashes, I opened the terminal to debug the program and i get this error message

```
*** Error in `monodevelop': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00005557e9c5c570 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bcb)[0x7fc0a2cedbcb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76f96)[0x7fc0a2cf3f96]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7778e)[0x7fc0a2cf478e]
[0x42104130]
======= Memory map: ========
41250000-41260000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
41d01000-42105000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
5557e584e000-5557e5beb000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8401707                    /usr/bin/mono-sgen
5557e5dea000-5557e5def000 r--p 0039c000 08:03 8401707                    /usr/bin/mono-sgen
5557e5def000-5557e5df9000 rw-p 003a1000 08:03 8401707                    /usr/bin/mono-sgen
5557e5df9000-5557e5e2c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
5557e74e3000-5557e9de0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7fc0477ff000-7fc047800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc047800000-7fc048000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc048000000-7fc048021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc048021000-7fc04c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04c7f9000-7fc04c7fa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04c7fa000-7fc04cffa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04cffa000-7fc04cffb000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04cffb000-7fc04d7fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04d7fb000-7fc04d7fc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04d7fc000-7fc04dffc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04effe000-7fc04efff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc04efff000-7fc04f7ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc050000000-7fc050123000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc050123000-7fc054000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc054000000-7fc054021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc054021000-7fc058000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc058000000-7fc058021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc058021000-7fc05c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc05c000000-7fc05c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc05c021000-7fc060000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc060000000-7fc060021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc060021000-7fc064000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc064000000-7fc064039000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc064039000-7fc068000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc068000000-7fc068029000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc068029000-7fc06c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06cdfa000-7fc06ce13000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8653795                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fc06ce13000-7fc06d013000 ---p 00019000 08:03 8653795                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fc06d013000-7fc06d016000 r--p 00019000 08:03 8653795                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fc06d016000-7fc06d017000 rw-p 0001c000 08:03 8653795                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7fc06d017000-7fc06d04e000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8396114                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
7fc06d04e000-7fc06d24e000 ---p 00037000 08:03 8396114                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
7fc06d24e000-7fc06d251000 r--p 00037000 08:03 8396114                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
7fc06d251000-7fc06d252000 rw-p 0003a000 08:03 8396114                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcroco-0.6.so.3.0.1
7fc06d252000-7fc06d287000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8396150                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2.40.16
7fc06d287000-7fc06d486000 ---p 00035000 08:03 8396150                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2.40.16
7fc06d486000-7fc06d487000 r--p 00034000 08:03 8396150                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2.40.16
7fc06d487000-7fc06d488000 rw-p 00035000 08:03 8396150                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2.40.16
7fc06d488000-7fc06d508000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06d50c000-7fc06d58c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06d590000-7fc06d610000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06d6e7000-7fc06d747000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 17924107                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fc06d747000-7fc06d749000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8653049                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so
7fc06d749000-7fc06d948000 ---p 00002000 08:03 8653049                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so
7fc06d948000-7fc06d949000 r--p 00001000 08:03 8653049                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so
7fc06d949000-7fc06d94a000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 8653049                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so
7fc06d94a000-7fc06d94b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06d94b000-7fc06db4b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06db4b000-7fc06db54000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06db54000-7fc06dd4c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06dd4c000-7fc06de4c000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 17891337                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fc06de4c000-7fc06decc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06dece000-7fc06df7b000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8652875                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
7fc06e17c000-7fc06e1fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e1ff000-7fc06e208000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e208000-7fc06e500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e537000-7fc06e549000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8654120                    /usr/lib/mono/gac/I18N.West/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/I18N.West.dll
7fc06e549000-7fc06e553000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8654114                    /usr/lib/mono/gac/I18N/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/I18N.dll
7fc06e553000-7fc06e574000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8791068                    /usr/lib/mono/gac/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/4.84.0.0__1b03e6acf1164f73/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
7fc06e574000-7fc06e5f4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e5f8000-7fc06e678000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e67c000-7fc06e6fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e700000-7fc06e800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e801000-7fc06e805000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e806000-7fc06e80c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e80c000-7fc06e80e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06e80e000-7fc06e85b000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308466                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/Mono.Cecil.dll
7fc06e85b000-7fc06e871000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8791006                    /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
7fc06e871000-7fc06e8f2000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9182379                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/NuGet.Core.dll
7fc06e8f2000-7fc06e96f000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9182380                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement.dll
7fc06e96f000-7fc06e9b9000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308399                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/BackendBindings/MonoDevelop.CBinding.dll
7fc06e9b9000-7fc06e9da000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9182395                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment.Linux.dll
7fc06e9da000-7fc06ea20000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9182397                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment.dll
7fc06ea20000-7fc06eb25000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06eb25000-7fc06edcb000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308474                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/ICSharpCode.NRefactory.CSharp.dll
7fc06edcb000-7fc06edd4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06edd4000-7fc06ee0c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06ee0c000-7fc06ee3c000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308424                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/MonoDevelop.GtkCore.dll
7fc06ee3c000-7fc06ee76000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308426                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libsteticui.dll
7fc06ee76000-7fc06ef16000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308429                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic.dll
7fc06ef16000-7fc06ef1f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06ef1f000-7fc06f117000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06f117000-7fc06f13a000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8652896                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
7fc06f13a000-7fc06f1d6000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8787824                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/crosextra/Carlito-Regular.ttf
7fc06f1d6000-7fc06f1db000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 19926125                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.24.so
7fc06f1db000-7fc06f3da000 ---p 00005000 08:03 19926125                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.24.so
7fc06f3da000-7fc06f3db000 r--p 00004000 08:03 19926125                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.24.so
7fc06f3db000-7fc06f3dc000 rw-p 00005000 08:03 19926125                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.24.so
7fc06f3dc000-7fc06f3de000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 19923365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fc06f3de000-7fc06f5dd000 ---p 00002000 08:03 19923365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fc06f5dd000-7fc06f5de000 r--p 00001000 08:03 19923365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fc06f5de000-7fc06f5df000 rw-p 00002000 08:03 19923365                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7fc06f5df000-7fc06f5e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06f5e0000-7fc06f5fb000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9182423                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences.dll
7fc06f5fb000-7fc06f604000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06f604000-7fc06f87e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06f87e000-7fc06f880000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06f880000-7fc06f889000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06f889000-7fc06fb3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc06fb3c000-7fc06fb3f000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8521125                    /usr/lib/cli/pango-sharp-2.0/libpangosharpglue-2.so
7fc06fb3f000-7fc06fd3e000 ---p 00003000 08:03 8521125                    /usr/lib/cli/pango-sharp-2.0/libpangosharpglue-2.so
7fc06fd3e000-7fc06fd3f000 r--p 00002000 08:03 8521125                    /usr/lib/cli/pango-sharp-2.0/libpangosharpglue-2.so
7fc06fd3f000-7fc06fd40000 rw-p 00003000 08:03 8521125                    /usr/lib/cli/pango-sharp-2.0/libpangosharpglue-2.so
7fc06fd40000-7fc06fd46000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8521116                    /usr/lib/cli/gdk-sharp-2.0/libgdksharpglue-2.so
7fc06fd46000-7fc06ff45000 ---p 00006000 08:03 8521116                    /usr/lib/cli/gdk-sharp-2.0/libgdksharpglue-2.so
7fc06ff45000-7fc06ff46000 r--p 00005000 08:03 8521116                    /usr/lib/cli/gdk-sharp-2.0/libgdksharpglue-2.so
7fc06ff46000-7fc06ff47000 rw-p 00006000 08:03 8521116                    /usr/lib/cli/gdk-sharp-2.0/libgdksharpglue-2.so
7fc06ff47000-7fc070000000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8652876                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
7fc070000000-7fc070022000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc070022000-7fc074000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc074000000-7fc074001000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc074001000-7fc074016000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9182378                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement/Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll
7fc074016000-7fc074023000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc074023000-7fc074056000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308459                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/bin/Mono.Debugging.dll
7fc074056000-7fc074061000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12588765                   /var/cache/fontconfig/945677eb7aeaf62f1d50efc3fb3ec7d8-le64.cache-4
7fc074061000-7fc074074000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12585154                   /var/cache/fontconfig/d52a8644073d54c13679302ca1180695-le64.cache-4
7fc074074000-7fc074301000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc074301000-7fc074306000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc074306000-7fc07430c000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12589525                   /var/cache/fontconfig/3047814df9a2f067bd2d96a2b9c36e5a-le64.cache-4
7fc07430c000-7fc07430f000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12589523                   /var/cache/fontconfig/e49e89034d371f0f9de17aab02136486-le64.cache-4
7fc07430f000-7fc07431b000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12589207                   /var/cache/fontconfig/d589a48862398ed80a3d6066f4f56f4c-le64.cache-4
7fc07431b000-7fc074324000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12590995                   /var/cache/fontconfig/d0972c3d32f097851eb916381fc38920-le64.cache-4
7fc074324000-7fc07432b000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12588152                   /var/cache/fontconfig/53d14c92082a93e67d5078324eb314ca-le64.cache-4
7fc07432b000-7fc074338000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12590996                   /var/cache/fontconfig/8f02d4cb045bd6ce15663e43f347c9f8-le64.cache-4
7fc074338000-7fc07433e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc07433e000-7fc07439e000 rw-s 00000000 00:05 17760264                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fc07439e000-7fc07439f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc07439f000-7fc074b9f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc074b9f000-7fc074bd5000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8524871                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fc074bd5000-7fc074dd5000 ---p 00036000 08:03 8524871                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fc074dd5000-7fc074ddb000 r--p 00036000 08:03 8524871                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fc074ddb000-7fc074ddc000 rw-p 0003c000 08:03 8524871                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7fc074ddc000-7fc074e0b000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8653796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fc074e0b000-7fc07500b000 ---p 0002f000 08:03 8653796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fc07500b000-7fc07500d000 r--p 0002f000 08:03 8653796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fc07500d000-7fc07500e000 rw-p 00031000 08:03 8653796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7fc07500e000-7fc07502e000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9706293                    /usr/share/icons/mate/icon-theme.cache
7fc07502e000-7fc07504a000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8525646                    /usr/share/icons/gnome/icon-theme.cache
7fc07504a000-7fc07505a000 r--p 00000000 08:03 10653856                   /usr/share/icons/Faba/icon-theme.cache
7fc07505a000-7fc0750ad000 r--p 00000000 08:03 10766432                   /usr/share/icons/Moka/icon-theme.cache
7fc0750ad000-7fc07511c000 r--p 00000000 08:03 8521104                    /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
7fc07511c000-7fc07522c000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9048844                    /usr/lib/mono/gac/monodoc/1.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/monodoc.dll
7fc07522c000-7fc07523c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc07523c000-7fc075344000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc075344000-7fc075348000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12588715                   /var/cache/fontconfig/246184dc75a16901ca37d96895904249-le64.cache-4
7fc075348000-7fc0753c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc0753c8000-7fc0753c9000 r--s 00000000 08:03 12585501                   /var/cache/fontconfig/32d4f95bd5d69a78cf8aaeeec87c8f3f-le64.cache-4
7fc0753c9000-7fc0753ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8652832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fc0753ce000-7fc0755cd000 ---p 00005000 08:03 8652832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fc0755cd000-7fc0755ce000 r--p 00004000 08:03 8652832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fc0755ce000-7fc0755cf000 rw-p 00005000 08:03 8652832                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7fc0755cf000-7fc0755d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 19926126                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7fc0755d9000-7fc0757d9000 ---p 0000a000 08:03 19926126                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7fc0757d9000-7fc0757da000 r--p 0000a000 08:03 19926126                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7fc0757da000-7fc0757db000 rw-p 0000b000 08:03 19926126                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
7fc0757db000-7fc0757e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fc0757e1000-7fc075804000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8521123                    /usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/libgtksharpglue-2.so
7fc075804000-7fc075a04000 ---p 00023000 08:03 8521123                    /usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/libgtksharpglue-2.so
7fc075a04000-7fc075a05000 r--p 00023000 08:03 8521123                    /usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/libgtksharpglue-2.so
7fc075a05000-7fc075a06000 rw-p 00024000 08:03 8521123                    /usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/libgtksharpglue-2.so
7fc075a06000-7fc075acf000 r--p 00000000 08:03 9308403                    /usr/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/BackendBindings/MonoDevelop.CSharpBinding.dll
7fc075acf000-7fc075ad6000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8396316                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7fc075ad6000-7fc075cd6000 ---p 00007000 08:03 8396316                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7fc075cd6000-7fc075cd7000 r--p 00007000 08:03 8396316                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7fc075cd7000-7fc075cd8000 rw-p 00008000 08:03 8396316                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
7fc075cd8000-7fc075d03000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8398140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7fc075d03000-7fc075f02000 ---p 0002b000 08:03 8398140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7fc075f02000-7fc075f03000 r--p 0002a000 08:03 8398140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7fc075f03000-7fc075f04000 rw-p 0002b000 08:03 8398140                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
7fc075f04000-7fc075f0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8396469                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1
7fc075f0d000-7fc07610c000 ---p 00009000 08:03 8396469                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1
7fc07610c000-7fc07610d000 r--p 00008000 08:03 8396469                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1
7fc07610d000-7fc07610e000 rw-p 00009000 08:03 8396469                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1
7fc07610e000-7fc076123000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8398228                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.3.11
7fc076123000-7fc076322000 ---p 00015000 08:03 8398228                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.3.11
7fc076322000-7fc076323000 r--p 00014000 08:03 8398228                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.3.11
7fc076323000-7fc076324000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 8398228                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtdb.so.1.3.11
7fc076324000-7fc07632c000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8400203                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.7
7fc07632c000-7fc07652b000 ---p 00008000 08:03 8400203                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.7
7fc07652b000-7fc07652c000 r--p 00007000 08:03 8400203                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.7
7fc07652c000-7fc07652d000 rw-p 00008000 08:03 8400203                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.7
7fc07652d000-7fc076532000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8401967                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
7fc076532000-7fc076732000 ---p 00005000 08:03 8401967                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
7fc076732000-7fc076733000 r--p 00005000 08:03 8401967                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
7fc076733000-7fc076734000 rw-p 00006000 08:03 8401967                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0.1.0
7fc076734000-7fc076745000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8401978                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5
7fc076745000-7fc076944000 ---p 00011000 08:03 8401978                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5
7fc076944000-7fc076945000 r--p 00010000 08:03 8401978                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5
7fc076945000-7fc076946000 rw-p 00011000 08:03 8401978                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcanberra.so.0.2.5
7fc076946000-7fc076951000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 19923139                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7fc076951000-7fc076b51000 ---p 0000b000 08:03 19923139                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7fc076b51000-7fc076b52000 r--p 0000b000 08:03 19923139                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7fc076b52000-7fc076b53000 rw-p 0000c000 08:03 19923139                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7fc076b53000-7fc076b6a000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 8396157                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6.3.0
7fc076b6a000-7fc076d6a000 ---p 00017000 08:03 8396157                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6.3.0
7fc076d6a000-7fc076d6b000 r--p 00017000 08:03 8396157                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6.3.0
```

I the few solutions I found were on the Debian bug tracker but they involve installing the package from flatpak,even trying to save a file generates an error:

```
*** Error in `monodevelop': double free or corruption (out): 0x000055c1885d1950 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bcb)[0x7faf44036bcb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76f96)[0x7faf4403cf96]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7778e)[0x7faf4403d78e]
[0x42186090]
```

As I said, i searched in google but some results never mention monodevelop at all and others just mention similar problems but with their own problem.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Also seeing this problem on the version of MonoDevelop from Lubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0):

The crash appears to have to do with the Welcome Screen. If I open the .sln file by `monodevelop filename.sln`, skipping the Welcome Screen, the problem does not occur.

EDITED: my previous solution about installing `mono-xsp` is not related.